artifactory debian virtual repo does not hold latest metadata from its included repos
We're running 2 artifactoy 7.77.5 instances

one in lab (where we push our .deb packages)
one in prod (where we replicate our .deb packages)

Here's what we're are doing

pushing .deb package into local debian repo: releases-deb-lab
syncing .deb packages every minute from releases-deb-lab into remote-releases-deb-lab
grouping remote repo "remote-release-deb-lab" into virtual repo releases-deb

# arti prod                                                   # arti lab

[releases-deb](virtual debian repo)
remote-releases-deb-lab (remote debian repo) <------------ releases-deb-lab (local debian repo)

Reality
remote repo works as expected
If we configure directly the remote-repo remote-release-deb-lab on our debian clients, the freshly pushed package can be seen, after one apt update && apt-cache madison <package-name>
virtual repo does not work as expected
If we configure the virtual repo releases-deb, then we have to issue  apt update two times in order to see the new package version in apt-cache madison <package-name>
alternatively
After seen the new package in the logs from remote-replication, we can also hit the recalculate index in order to have the new package available after one apt update && apt-cache madison <package-name>
FYI: on both - virtual and remote repo - the Metadata Retrieval Cache Period (Sec) is set to 0
This feature is working fine for rpm repos, but obviously not for debian.
